# Fingerprint reader malfunction HP dv7

Tags: login, security, hp, scanner, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion dv7 with a Validity VFS301 Fingerprint reader. I have tried multiple fingerprint reading software, including Fprint, but all of them give the same problem:

It registers that there is a fingerprint reader, and when I scan my finger the first time (so that I can enrol my fingerprints) it works fine and records it, but when the software tells me to scan it for the second time (I think you have to scan it about 5 times in the enrol process) the scanner will not pick up my fingerprint. After I have restarted the software, the same thing happens: I can scan the first time, but not thereafter.

I have discovered that in System Settings -> User Accounts there is an option for 'Fingerprint Login', but I still get the exact same issue when I try to enrol my fingerprints.
Does anyone know what the solution might be? It would be really nice if I could get it working again.
Thanks in advance!